# Byte of 128 or higher in JavaScript is manipulated when send to C++ application. How to stop this?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I'm creating a test network where a node.js application communicates to a C++ application via ZeroMQ using Google Protocol Buffers for the message structure.

Data from C++ to JavaScript can be serialized, sent, received, and deserialized without issue. However, I'm having an issue moving in the opposite direction.

If the Protobuf message going from JavaScript to C++ contains an integer with a set value over 127, the data is manipulated some where along the wire where many of the bytes of the payload change.

Note that every message sent in both directions has a 4 byte header that works (seammingly) correctly so I won't include that in the conversation for now.

I've noticed that on the JS side before sending, the bytes for the protobuf serialized data will look something like this:

`26,4,129,192,136,24,64,40` stored in type Buffer (npm).

However, on the C++ side after receiving, I'm getting:

`26,4,239,191,189,239,191,189` stored in a std::string container.

I have verified that the bytes in the JS Buffer do not change up to the point that ZeroMQ sub is called. However, after that I can't tell what happens or when the values change.

I've tried forcing any use of Buffer types to Uint8Arrays with no luck. I haven't tried much else because I'm not sure what the issue is in the slightest.

This is the basic flow of the message creation on the JavaScript side.

```
var data = new ProtoData.Data1();
data.setTemp(128); // type is int32
var payload = data.serializeBinary();
var size = payload.length + 4; // 16 bits
var head1 = 4; // 8 bits
var head2 = 4; // 8 bits
var payload_buf = Buffer.from(payload);
// create the header
var header = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
header.writeUInt16LE(size, 0);
header.writeUInt8(head1, 2);
header.writeUInt8(head2, 3);
var msg = Buffer.concat([header, payload_buf]);
zmqPubSock.sock.send(msg);
```

Receiving this on the C++ side will have a completely different message received. Keep in mind that if `data.setTemp()` had a value of < 127 then this message would be received on the C++ side without issue.

Comment: `239,191,189` this looks like the UTF-8 multibyte for the codePoint `0xFFFD`

Comment: @Thomas is there any reason that would be added in the buffer?

Comment: Can confirm that it's the unknown character pattern... https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/466 but why and can we alleviate this? It seems to be an issue for any byte over 127